# How to capture Jenkins build Number thru Java code

Tags: jenkins

I have a requirement to send the Jenkins Build Number back to JSF page.I am invoking the Jenkins URL as below:

```
httpPost post = new HttpPost(getUrl); 
try { if(uefe != null) {   post.setEntity(uefe); } 
HttpResponse response=client.execute(post); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

---

Please suggest which method will give me the Jenkins Build Number and code snippet too
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Build numbers are not assigned on the queueing, but only when the job actually gets executed.

You can however evaluate the *Location* header to get the url of the queued item, which you then can query in intervals to see if it got started. Once it got started you can get its build number.

See [this response](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12827?focusedCommentId=201381&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-201381) given on a related feature request, it explains the reasoning very well and also gives a possible solution. Check also the resulting [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31039) comments regarding the possible solution.

### For reference:

[Source 1st link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12827)

[image]

---

[Source 2nd link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31039)

[image]